# Java Flight Recorder -- missing File Write/Read events

Tags: java, jvm, java-8, jvm-hotspot, jmc

I am analyzing java8 JVM-process with Java Mission Control + Flight Recorder.

When checking the recording under **I/O** tab, it says:

```
"Event types 'File Write' 'File Read' are not enabled in this recording"
```

When creating the recording, in the recording wizard, last dialog **Event Details...**, as far as I can see, everything already has **Enabled=True**, but I cannot find any setting for **File Write/Read**...

How do I enable them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File and Socket Read/Write events are only available in JDK 7u40+ and JDK 8u20+

Comment: *Comment from [Ying-Rong Chen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2781228/ying-rong-chen):* File Write/Read events are also missing in JDK 7u60. I think it's an issue of the bundled JMC 5.3 in JDk 7u60/8u05.

Comment: The events are available in 7u60, can been seen by doing:
 
**java -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -jar -XX:StartFlightRecording=duration=60s ..\demo\jfc\Java2D\Java2Demo.jar**  and then **jcmd Java2Demo JFR.check verbose=true**

Perhaps a saved template from JDK 8 is being used in the JMC recording wizard?